# Counting triangles in a hexagon

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I am struggling with a problem right now. I have a problem which is related to matching and graph theory. I have given text data which is the relation of the vertexes. I need to find the number of triangles in that graph according to the given text data.
I have attached an explanation image.

[image]
I have tried add weights but it did not work. I have tried to find them by using brute force. Here is my code:

```
path = r"triangles.txt"
file = open(path,"r+")
f1 = file.readlines()
splitted_list = []
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
e = []
f = []
g = []
h = []
j = []
k = []

for i in f1:
    splitted_list.append(i.strip().split("-"))

elements = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k]
values = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","j","k"]
for i in range(10):
    for t in values:
        for j in splitted_list:
            for k in range(len(j)):
                if t in j:
                    if j[k] not in elements[i] and j[k] !=t:
                        elements[i].append(j[k])

#expected output
# a = ["b","c","f","j","d","g","k","e"]
# b = ["a","c","d","e","f","h","k","j"]
# c = ["b","f","j","a","d","e"]
# d = ["a","g","k","e","c","b"]
# e = ["a","b","c","d","g","h","j","k"]
# f = ["b","h","k","j","c","a"]
# g = ["d","a","k","e","h","j"]
# h = ["g","f","b","e","k","j"]
# j = ["b","f","c","a","h","g","e","k"]
# k = ["j","e","g","d","a","h","f","b"]

#output
a =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k']
#all the elements are also have the same value 
#a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=j=k
```

Another problem is what should I do to count the triangles?
I thought I should use count to get every relation between three nodes which is also a brute force.
Do you have an easy method for this?

I have attached a manuscript about counting triangles on big graphs if it would help anyone to figure out this problem.
https://i11www.iti.kit.edu/extra/publications/sw-fclt-05_t.pdf

Sorry for this long problem. Hope you have time to answer.
Thanks.

Comment: first I wondered if it could be done with language Prolog because there are some relations between elements. Next idea to create first graph but I have no idea how later use this graph. Last idea to create dictionary `{"a": set("b", ...), "b":set(...)}` (something like "neighborhood matrix") and next for every pair use `set() | set()` to find all point which can be used as third point in triangle. If keep all results in set (with) then maybe it will not keep the same triangle created with other pair - and then you can use `len()` to count all elements in `set()` and get number of triangles.

Comment: I read your PDF and `algorithm “forward”` seems nice. After creating "adjacency data structure" ("neighborhood matrix") rest is easy because there is pseudo code. I have some code but I don't know if it gives correct results. If you have example datas with results then add to question.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the answer. I thought that too. I was going to use if there would  be dublication of string elements. Instead I made a loop to prevent duplicate. I also though symmetric relations,additionally some facts about graph theory(reflection,antisymmetric,transitivity). I was going to use for loop to count every 3 pair element relation(I don't know how). I am sorry but I do not have example data to add. Everything is in this topic. Do you have extra suggestion ?

Comment: I put my cod e in answer with few examples which I created but I don't know if al results are correct - I would have to use paper and ballpen to test it manually but for example it would be 55 triangles to check :)

Comment: @furas What if I describe the relations of each nodes and calculate the solution according to perfect graph properties. Is this possible? I mean how do I get the general formula for edges and triangles by using vertex?

Comment: I had graphs long time ago as a student and later I didn't have to use them - so I can't help more. Simply I don't remember theory. And frankly for me "coding" is more insteresting then "maths"

Comment: @furas Thank you for your tries but the only problem that I have in this example is where we find 55 triangles but It should be 35 :/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUTDm5b82sk

Comment: you should get all 55 results and check on image if this triange exists. This way I found in results `a c f` which is not triangle but line. And it should be more results which are lines. Now it is time to find method to recognize lines in results.

Comment: I resolved problem with lines - see new code in answer. I keep `"a-b", "a-c-f-j", "a-d-g-k", etc.` as list of lines `[ ["a", "b"], ["a", "c", "f", "j"], ["a", "d", "g", "k"], etc.]` and later I can check if nodes `(s,t,v)` are on the same line.

Comment: @furas you are fantastic hahaha. Actually I was exactly looking for the same method by creating an exception list that contains all the linear line. I was looking for the string method and going to update the answer after finishing my exception list. Thank you so much. You are the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your PDF and algorithm `"forward"` seems nice and easy.

After creating `"adjacency data structure"` rest is easy because there is pseudo code.

I put code but I don't know if it gives correct results.

I keep every triangle as tuple with corners in alphabetic order so later it is easer to compare duplications. Using `set()` it automatically removes duplications.

BTW: in comments I uses name "neighborhood matrix" but I was thinking about something like "adjacency data structure"

```
text = '''a-b
a-c-f-j
a-d-g-k
a-e
b-c-d-e
b-f-h-k
b-j
e-g-h-j
e-k
j-k'''

# --- create Adj ---

Adj = dict()

lines = []

for row in text.strip().split('\n'):
    all_items = set(row.split('-'))
    lines.append(all_items)
    for item in all_items:
        if item not in Adj:
            Adj[item] = set()
        rest = all_items - set(item)
        Adj[item].update(rest)
        #Adj[item].update(all_items)
        #Adj[item].remove(item)

print('--- nodes ---')
nodes = sorted(Adj.keys())
print(nodes)

print('--- lines ---')
for line in lines:
    print(line)

print('--- Adj ---')
for key in sorted(Adj.keys()):
    print(key, list(sorted(Adj[key])))


# --- create triangles ---

triangles = list()
A = {x:set() for x in nodes} # create empty A(v)

for s in nodes:
    for t in Adj[s]:
        if s < t:
            for v in A[s] & A[t]:
                # check if nodes not on one line
                is_line = False
                for line in lines:
                    if s in line and t in line and v in line:
                        is_line = True
                        break
                if not is_line:
                    triangles.append(tuple(sorted( (s,v,t) )))
                    #print(*triangles[-1])
            A[t].add(s)

# --- count triangles ---

print('--- number of triangles ---')
print(len(triangles))
#print(len(set(triangles)))

# --- show triangles in alphabetic order ---

print('--- triangles ---')
for triangle in sorted(triangles):
    print(*triangle)
```

---

I use other examples:

rectangle with diagonals:

```
text = '''a-b
a-c
a-d
b-c
b-d
c-d
'''
```

Example from PDF:

```
text = '''a-b
a-c
a-d
a-e
b-c
b-d
d-e
'''
```

[image]

PDF shows 2 triangles but there are 3 triangles in this graph

```
a b c
a b d
a d e
```

I think PDF has few mistakes in table near this image.